# connecting to db2 from spark Scala using SSL certificate

Tags: db2, ssl-certificate

I want to connect to DB2 from Spark(Scala) code using SSL certificate. Could you please provide format of the connection string and what are properties required to establish a connection.

Answer (score 0):

`jdbc:db2://host:port/database:sslConnection=true;sslCertLocation=/full/path/to/certificate/file;`
or
`jdbc:db2://host:port/database:sslConnection=true;sslTrustStoreLocation=/full/path/to/truststore/file;sslTrustStorePassword=truststorePassword;`

Don't remove the ending `;` character of URL.
Note, that Db2 uses different ports for SSL and non-SSL connections, and SSL support must be configured on the server side properly.

Useful links:
[Configuring connections under the IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ to use TLS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=ctsijdc-configuring-connections-under-data-server-driver-jdbc-sqlj-use-tls)
[Common IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ properties for all supported database products](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=pdsdjs-common-data-server-driver-jdbc-sqlj-properties-all-database-products)